# Recommendation for Filter slider [iOS]

Tags: ios, uislider

I would like to achieve something like this:

[image]

This image comes from [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/national-parks-by-national/id518426085?mt=8) app.

My question is, should I rely on something like [this](https://github.com/ShadyElyaski/ios-filter-control), do it by own, or even if there is some other 3rd pary libary, that I am not aware of, that could be recommended.

I am trying to get more of an opinion, than an actually technical question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is:

1. go with the github class you linked;
2. check your UI concept in your running app;
3. if the UI works well, then either stick with that given implementation, or improve it or look for another one, or build your own.

I think the most important point, when dealing with UI, is (2): you need as soon as possible to be able to test your UI design. Possibly including other people's feedback.

The github control will do wonders to that aim. Then you can also judge better if it is fit for you you or you want something different.

You might even discover that the UI concept is not good for your app, once you see it running, and you will have saved a bunch of time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd build my own. It's pretty simple: overriding touch events and moving "indicator" view frame in TouchesMoved selector.